# Compare csv file

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk

I'm comparing two CSV files which have two columns: file name, and the hash of the file. I need to find out the file which has a mismatching hash and a new file from `first.csv` which does not exist in the `second.csv`. I want to output such file names, like `BlockchainContextHelp.tsv` and `new1.tsv`

```sh
first.csv
#File,SHA-1
BlockchainContextHelp.tsv,1234562eertyrtyty3rer
new.tsv,7777hhrtdk12kefk23kfmsd

second.csv
#File,SHA-1
BlockchainContextHelp.tsv,123522234rrtkoe98877
new.tsv,7777hhrtdk12kefk23kfmsd
new1.tsv,3456734dfkekeruer7ererj
```

Below is what I tried so far.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
while IFS="," read f1 f2;do
        while IFS="," read c1 c2;do
                if [ $f2 != $c2 ]
                then
                        echo "$f1"
                fi
        done < second.csv
done < first.csv
```

Appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` is better tool for text processing. You may use:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {
   FS = OFS = ","                # set input/output field separator as ,
}
NR == FNR {                      # While processing the first file
   map[$1] = $2                  # store the second column by the first
   next                          # move to next record
}
!($1 in map) || map[$1] != $2 {  # In 2nd file if $1 not in map and 2nd 
                                 # column of second file is not same as 
                                 # what is in map
   print $1                      # print first column
}' first.csv second.csv
```

```
BlockchainContextHelp.tsv
new1.tsv
```

Comment: Thank you. I have accepted your answer, great help!

Comment: I'm trying to see if there is any other way than using awk, as awk is always difficult to understand and learn.

Comment: `awk` is least error prone for this. I will add more explanation